# Customize Salesforce Authorization Page

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

We are using Salesforce WEB APIs and authentication using connected app.

We use below url to login.

https://URL/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={successURL}

after login into this URL we get authorization page having 2 buttons Accept & Deny. Once user clicks Accept, we get redirected to url having code as querystring which we used to get access token.

Once user clicks Accept button, from newt time when user logs in, he/she gets white page with one line Remote Access Application Authorization. Is there any way we can customize thia white page from Salesforce side?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're landing at the default callback URL for the OAuth server flow (`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success`), which means your Connected App is configured incorrectly, or your request is written incorrectly. When configured correctly, you should be redirected to something like `www.mysite.com/callback?code=ABCD`, where your server should be completing the process. There's no way to customize this page, as it is a global default for all OAuth flows that don't get redirected back to another server. Users should not ordinarily ever see this page. You'll want to read the [Understanding the Web Server OAuth Authentication Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) documentation to figure out exactly where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am redirecting to www.mysite.com/callback?code=ABCD url like this. But that whicte page that I get is very bad in terms of user experience so wanted to have this updated. It is from client feedback so need to find a fix.

Comment: Above answer does not provide me solution of problem I got but mentioned process I follow in my application. My challenge is to customize auth page mentioned in screenshot with some user friendly UI from Salesforce side.

Comment: @RaviKanasagra That page is not customizable. There's something wrong with your flow, because you're landing on that page, and that should not happen. It's a catch-all page for when something goes wrong. Check your OAuth parameters, and make sure they match the configuration in Salesforce.